# I want to query between two dates in sqlite with two textbox(textbox4.text and textbox5.text = variable) in form

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Dim query As String = "select * from mytable where strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tarih) between **'TextBox4.text'** and **'TextBox5.text'** "

Can not assign query variable ?
Datagridview result = empty

info :Datagridview date format = 2018-01-01 17:42:24

```
    Dim btarihyil As String
    btarihyil = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString.Substring(6, 4)
    Dim btarihay As String
    btarihay = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString.Substring(3, 2)
    Dim btarihgun As String
    btarihgun = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString.Substring(0, 2)
    TextBox4.Text = btarihyil & "-" & btarihay & "-" & btarihgun

    Dim bttarihyil As String
    bttarihyil = DateTimePicker3.Value.ToString.Substring(6, 4)
    Dim bttarihay As String
    bttarihay = DateTimePicker3.Value.ToString.Substring(3, 2)
    Dim bttarihgun As String
    bttarihgun = DateTimePicker3.Value.ToString.Substring(0, 2)

    TextBox4.Text = btarihyil & "-" & btarihay & "-" & btarihgun
    TextBox5.Text = bttarihyil & "-" & bttarihay & "-" & bttarihgun

    Dim Yol As String = "Data Source=database1.s3db;version=3;new=False"
    Using MyConn As New SQLiteConnection(Yol)
        If (MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            MyConn.Open()
        End If
        Dim Sorgu As String = "select * from mytable where strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tarih) between 'TextBox4.text' and 'TextBox5.text' "
        Using MyCmd As New SQLiteCommand(Sorgu, MyConn)
            Dim Da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(MyCmd)
            Dim Ds As New DataSet
            Dim Dt As New DataTable
            Ds.Reset()
            Da.Fill(Ds)
            Dt = Ds.Tables(0)

            Dim Bs As New BindingSource With {.DataSource = Dt}
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Bs
            Bs.MoveLast()

            MyConn.Close()
            MyCmd.Dispose()
            MyConn.Dispose()
        End Using
    End Using


End Sub
```

Comment: Where is C# code?

Comment: sorry for the long error i am re edit

Comment: You are using the literal string 'TextBox4.text' in the query, not the value of the TextBox. Use SqliteParameters to add the values.

Comment: example :Dim Sorgu As String = "select * from mytable where strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tarih) between values(@firstdate) and values(@lastdate)"

Comment: MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstdate", TextBox4.Text)
                MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastdate", TextBox5.Text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `"TextBox4.Text"` and `"TextBox5.Text"` literally in the query. That will not pass the values of `textboxes` to the query. So it will result in error.

Also you need to use parameterized query to avoid syntax errors.
Also I am not sure why you are using `strftime` function. That function is used just for formatting.

Following the code I re-written using parameterzied query approach.

```
Dim Yol As String = "Data Source=database1.s3db;version=3;new=False"
Using MyConn As New SQLiteConnection(Yol)
    If (MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
        MyConn.Open()
    End If
    Dim Sorgu As String = "select * from mytable where tarih between @startDate and @endDate "
    Using MyCmd As New SQLiteCommand(Sorgu, MyConn)
        Dim startDate as new SQLiteParameter("@startDate")
        startDate.Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
        Dim endDate as new SQLiteParameter("@endDate")
        endDate.Value = DateTimePicker3.Value
        MyCmd.Parameters.Add(startDate)
        MyCmd.Parameters.Add(endDate)

        Dim Da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(MyCmd)
        Dim Ds As New DataSet
        Dim Dt As New DataTable
        Ds.Reset()
        Da.Fill(Ds)
        Dt = Ds.Tables(0)

        Dim Bs As New BindingSource With {.DataSource = Dt}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Bs
        Bs.MoveLast()

        MyConn.Close()
        MyCmd.Dispose()
        MyConn.Dispose()
    End Using
End Using
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you Dim Sorgu As String = "select * from Hareketler where strftime('%Y-%m-%d',tarih) between @firstdate and @lastdate" WORKED

Comment: i use strftime function because datagridview data = 2018-01-01 17:42:24

Comment: Awesome... Glad to help